# overriding methods in C# and avoid duplicate code

Tags: c#, overriding

I would like to override a method, but i still want the parent method to be called when i override. When i try to use ***:base()*** to call parent method, it says ***unexpected token***.

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual void DoStuff() 
    {
       //some code
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public override void DoStuff() : base()
    {
       //some other code
    }
}
```

In java i would be :

```
super.DoStuff()
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. You need to manually call `base.DoStuff()` from the derived method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax, you can call the base method using the `base` keyword anywhere in the body of the method. The `:base()` syntax is only for constructors.

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual void DoStuff() 
    {
       //some code
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
         base.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks !

Comment: @DavidG wops, left in the original syntax, fixed